# Two TH02 Sensors to Grove Base Shield V2

Tags: arduino-uno

We are trying to connect two TH02 (Grove - Temperature&Humidity Sensor (High-Accuracy & Mini))  sensors to Grove Base Shield V2 that is connected to Arduino Wifi Uno.

We connected the each sensor alone to I2C of the Base shield and it is working just fine, but when we connect two, we cannot get simultaneous readings.

We are new to Arduino and we are trying ti figure out if these two sensors can be connected to I2C even if they have the same address.

Please tell if we need to provide more information. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like they have a fixed I2C address so, if I understand correctly, unfortunately you cannot address them individually if they're both on the same bus. Perhaps there's a way to multiplex the bus...

Comment: Get i2CScanner to confirm what mark has said (he is usually right).  This just scans the I2C bus and tell you what addresses respond to it.  (Its a useful Arduino program to have to hand anyway).  You can get chips that create a second I2C bus, can't remember the make or model, but they are out there.

Comment: I have done, and the TH02 sensor's address is 0x40. Is there a way we can connect one of the sensor to D2 or D4?